# What does (a+b) >>1 mean?

Tags: c++, operators

What does `int c = (a+b) >>1` mean in C++?

Comment: The question is meaningless until you explain what `a` and `b` are.

Comment: `c` is `1(true)` if `(a+b)` is *much greater" than `1` :-) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuchGreater.html

Comment: Watch out for overflow when you use '+' instead. http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: sorry, a and b are both ints.

Comment: thank you for all the answers, you guys have no idea how much you helped me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note, that there can't be any meaningful explanation of what your code means until you explain what `a` and `b` are.

Even if `a` and `b` are of built-in type, beware of the incorrect answers unconditionally claiming that built-in right shift is equivalent to division by 2. The equivalence only holds for non-negative values. The behavior of the `>>` operator for negative values is implementation-defined.

In other words, without extra information, the only thing that can be said is that the code calculates the "sum" `a + b` and "shifts" it right by 1 bit. I used quotes in the last sentence because in case of overloaded operators `+` and `>>` there's no way to predict what they are doing.

Comment: Agree, though, my answer was trying to address the intent of the code, rather than what it actually does.

Comment: In more detail, a twos-complement negative number starts with 1 (negative numbers are 2^n-x, where n is the number of bits used to store a number and x is the absolute value of the number). A strict bit-shift of that number to the left will replace this 1 with a zero; in decimal math the transformation would follow abs(x)/2+2^(n-1)

Comment: @KeithS: Right, and that's what AndreyT's point is: it's implementation-defined. On x86, there are two instructions, `SHR` and `SAR`. `SHR` does what you say: shifts in 0. `SAR` shifts in the top bit. So, since compilers are free to choose which instruction to use, you can get varied results.

Comment: What about the overflow? http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Answer (score 18):

It returns the average of `a` and `b`, rounded down. So, if `a` is 5 and `b` is 8, then the result is 6.

ETA: This method is busted if `a` and `b` add up to a negative number, like if both are negative, or if integer overflow occurs.

Comment: The `>> 1` is a particularly hack-y way of dividing by 2, because it bit-shifts to the right by 1.

Comment: @Quartz: Some people do it as a micro-optimisation because they think the compiler can't handle `/2` properly. I, of course, disagree.

Comment: Not correct in general case. Since `a + b` can be negative, the behavior of `>>` is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, but when you write >> 1, it looks like you are smarter:)

Comment: @AndreyT: Added a comment addressing your concern. :-)

Comment: I always disagree with the optimization with some tricky code. 20% of your code will use almost 80% performance of your systems. It must be the place to be optimized, not these things :)

Comment: In environments where using the >> operator on signed numbers implements sign extension, saying "exp >> 1" is a way of dividing by two with round-toward-negative-infinity.  It's too bad the C standard doesn't require implementations to handle it that way, since it would otherwise often be more useful than "/2".

Answer (score 6):

That depends on the type of c, a and b. If it's int then the above statement is the same as:

```
c = (a+b)/2;
```

`>>` means shift right one bit.

Comment: Read the question: it does say `int`. :-P

Comment: it doesn't say what a and b are.

Comment: If `a` or `b` is floating-point, then `>>` doesn't work and the program won't compile anyway. So, we'll safely assume they're both integral.

Comment: No, they may be user defined types.

Comment: Not the same if it's negative. If it's `unsigned int`, then that works.

Comment: @ybungalobill: do you have a source for that?  I'm pretty sure that arithmetic shifts are defined as shifts that use the high bit to fill in the missing bits.  As such shifting a negative number would always round down (i.e. -15>>1 == -8).

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi: Sorry I've already deleted my answer for another reason. Per your question: For right bit-shift it's implementation-define which bit is shifted for **negative** numbers (signed non-negative is OK), see [expr.shift]. For division it's actually defined that it's rounded towards zero thus I deleted my answer.

Comment: You just broke the merge sort, buddy 
http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Answer (score 2):

It means to add A to B, then bit-shift the result by one bit to the right. Bit-shifting a positive integer generally has the effect of multiplying or dividing by 2^n where n is the number of bits being shifted. So, this is roughly equivalent to (a+b)/2 in integer math (which has no remainders or fractional parts).

Comment: http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Answer (score 1):

It means that you add `a` and `b`, then shift the result one bit to the right.

It's the same as:

```
int c = (a + b) / 2;
```

Comment: Fail :)
http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, it's an average function utilizing the bit-shift operator in c++ (with some potential pitfalls in it) - by the existence of this question, the readability of this code is quite bad. Do your fellow programmer a favor and think about readability when you write code